# get template id of custom transaction email by template name

Tags: template, email, email-templates

Hi Can someone help me on this.

I need to send a custom email.

Currently all custom emails are send by setting the template id to a variable named $templateId as

```
$templateId = 20;
```

(or)

```
$templateId = Mage::getStoreConfig(self::XML_PATH_EMAIL_TEMPLATE, $storeId);
```

I want to be able to get the template id based on the email template name.
, say "NewEmailTemplate" is the email template name and the id is 10.

I want the id 10 by giving the template name.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```
 $mailTemplate = Mage::getModel('core/email_template')

 $localeCode = Mage::getStoreConfig('general/locale/code', $storeId);
 $templateId = $mailTemplate->loadDefault($templateId, $localeCode);
```

You may want to take a look at `sendTransactional` in `Mage_Core_Model_Email_Template`

```
public function sendTransactional($templateId, $sender, $email, $name, $vars=array(), $storeId=null)
{
    $this->setSentSuccess(false);
    if (($storeId === null) && $this->getDesignConfig()->getStore()) {
        $storeId = $this->getDesignConfig()->getStore();
    }

    if (is_numeric($templateId)) {
        $this->load($templateId);
    } else {
        $localeCode = Mage::getStoreConfig('general/locale/code', $storeId);
        $this->loadDefault($templateId, $localeCode);
    }
```

Comment: in this line did u mean  $templateId = $mailTemplate->loadDefault("NewEmail", $localeCode);

Comment: Yea... the template id can be either numeric or a string

Comment: Also, what method are you use to send email because if you use `sendTransactional` and setup your system.xml correctly then you would need to do all this work

Answer (score 0):

If anyone is looking for full sample code of how to send a Magento email based on an existing Magento email template, the following works well. It does not require any XML config.

```
// This is the name that you gave to the template in System -> Transactional Emails
$emailTemplate = Mage::getModel('core/email_template')->loadByCode('My Custom Email Template');

// These variables can be used in the template file by doing {{ var some_custom_variable }}
$emailTemplateVariables = array(
'some_custom_variable' => 'Hello World'
);

$processedTemplate = $emailTemplate->getProcessedTemplate($emailTemplateVariables);

$emailTemplate->setSenderName('Joe Bloggs');
$emailTemplate->setSenderEmail('test@test.com');
$emailTemplate->setTemplateSubject("Here is your subject");

$emailTemplate->send('recipient@test.com', 'Joanna Bloggs', $emailTemplateVariables);
```

Comment: I keep getting some php error when I do `Mage::getModel('core/email_template')->loadByCode()` or `Mage::getModel('core/email_template')->loadByAttribute()`. Magento seems to have a lot of control over the error logging so that it does not produce a log despite ini settings and error function calls in the code. The `MAGE_IS_DEVELOPER_MODE` httpd config setting turns on strict error processing and also can't be regulated with ini settings or function calls, perhaps due to Magento's httpd config overrides.

Answer (score 0):

Willster, good job. Your example works well.

Here is my part of code, that is on working shop currently:

```
$mailTemplate = Mage::getModel('core/email_template');
/* @var $mailTemplate Mage_Core_Model_Email_Template */

$templateId = $mailTemplate->loadByCode('Anfrage (Template)'); // custom transactional email template

$mailTemplate->setDesignConfig(array('area' => 'frontend'))
->setReplyTo($post['email'])
->sendTransactional(
    Mage::getStoreConfig($templateId),
    Mage::getStoreConfig(self::XML_PATH_EMAIL_SENDER),
    Mage::getStoreConfig(self::XML_PATH_EMAIL_RECIPIENT),
    null,
    array('data' => $postObject)
);
```